# Primeng multiSelect filter text need to clear on 'onPanelHide' event

Tags: primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Primeng multiSelect filter text need to clear on 'onPanelHide' event

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information on what to accomplish, what you already tried and where you failed. This will improve your chances to get an answer to your question. Here you will find more information on [ask] a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation specifies to use the callback `onPanelHide` https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

`<p-multiSelect (onPanelHide)="handlePanelHide()"  [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"></p-multiSelect>`

Then in your component you will perform your logic to do the filtering

`public handlePanelHide(): void {
 // Filter the options with your custom logic
}`